# installing windows phone sdk on win server 2008 r2

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Does anyone ever tried to install wp 7.1 SDK on win server 2008 r2 64-bit. I already have VS 2010 Premium installed.. but it keeps forcing to install VS2010 express and keep getting this error:

***ERROR LOG EVENT*** : DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express Prerequisites x64 is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Its actually possible to do this follow [This Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx).

For **7.1** as noted in the comments the only change is that vm_web.exe is now vm_web2.exe

That same comment says its been done on 2008r2 and in some posts i found while searching on google (i'll try this soon too).

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is not supported on Server versions of Windows. There might be workarounds, but I'd be prepared for crashes, emulator not working correctly and other unexpecteds.

Comment: Yeah right.. another stupid architecture from Microsoft whereas sharepoint only running on win server.. I'm coding both sharepoint and win phone.. how do i get both running on the same machine?

Comment: Try this workaround if you really have to install the SDK on a Server:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx

Comment: Frustrating? Absolutely! But comparing this to Sharepoint only running Windows Server misses the point. Sharepoint is a *server product* (that's what it does), so it makes some sense to restrict it to installing it on server operating systems. The situation with WP7 development certainly does not make sense in the same way: developers might reasonably want or need to be developing on client (Windows 7 or Vista) or server (Windows Server 2008) operating systems.

Comment: I think their story for business solutions on Windows Phone is still incomplete and suspect the emulator is implemented using some technologies that don't work well with servers. I'm not exactly sure what that would be - maybe some DirectX or driver issues or virtualization incompatibilities between the SKUs. Obviously it's something they decided to be of lesser business value than adding the features they did add in the past year and they do seem like a nice set of features that I will personally gladly take instead of server development support. Maybe Windows 8 will solve something...

Comment: @xyzzer.. I have tried the link.. the information is no longer valid since it was for wp SDK 7 not 7.1...    How can wp ever compete with iphone or adriod development if we are as developers are limited to develop only on the client machines such as win 7? by having this limitation it means that I have to have 2 PCs for both server and client.

Comment: @Visual Stuart .. it makes sense that Sharepoint is server solution..  what does not make sense is to limiting wp7 development on client only? why can;t we build wp7 on win server???

Comment: @user384080, yes, that's my point exactly. My assumption is that the WP7 team had to pick and choose which environments to test the tools, libraries, emulators, and so forth in. And there are a lot more developers, especially in their target audience, on Windows client operating systems than on server operating systems. At least that's my theory. That said, I do have WP7 projects compiling on a TFS build server running Windows Server 2008, following Justin Angel's instructions at http://justinangel.net/TFS2010WP7ContinuousIntegration. Note: that is compilation, not development.

Comment: I don't know why you would say it is not competitive with iPhone development since that can only be done on a Mac... :)
You can do both Sharepoint and WP7 on one box if you install both OS-s on one box.

Comment: @xyzzer .. you need to have client OS to do the development. At the moment i have only one pc and running server 2008 r2 plus the hyper-v cannot detect usb connection of wp7 so virtualization is not an option..

Comment: I was not saying virtualization - I don't really much like virtualization myself with it being limited and slow in many applications. I rather meant dual-boot for Win7/Win Server.